# ObjC Class identifiers & compiler magic?

Tags: objective-c

Consider:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject

+ (void) dump ;

@end

@implementation Foo

+ (Class) classOf1 {
    return self ;
}

+ (Class) classOf2 {
    return [Foo class] ;
}

+ (Class) classOf3 {
    return [[[Foo class] new] class] ;
}

+ (Class) classOf4 {
    return [[self new] class] ;
}

+ (Class) classOf5 {
    return [[[self alloc] init] class] ;
}

+ (Class) classOf6 {
    return [[[Foo alloc] init] class] ;
}

+ (Class) classOf7 {
    return [self class] ;
}

+ (void) dump {
    NSLog(@"classOf1 %@<0x%08.8lx>", [self classOf1], (unsigned long)[[self classOf1] hash]) ;
    NSLog(@"classOf2 %@<0x%08.8lx>", [self classOf2], (unsigned long)[[self classOf2] hash]) ;
    NSLog(@"classOf3 %@<0x%08.8lx>", [self classOf3], (unsigned long)[[self classOf3] hash]) ;
    NSLog(@"classOf4 %@<0x%08.8lx>", [self classOf4], (unsigned long)[[self classOf4] hash]) ;
    NSLog(@"classOf5 %@<0x%08.8lx>", [self classOf5], (unsigned long)[[self classOf5] hash]) ;
    NSLog(@"classOf6 %@<0x%08.8lx>", [self classOf6], (unsigned long)[[self classOf6] hash]) ;
    NSLog(@"classOf7 %@<0x%08.8lx>", [self classOf7], (unsigned long)[[self classOf7] hash]) ;
}

@end
```

And the output:

```
    2013-07-04 03:20:20.404 WC[29862:c07] classOf1 Foo<0x0002a2e4>
    2013-07-04 03:20:21.075 WC[29862:c07] classOf2 Foo<0x0002a2e4>
    2013-07-04 03:20:21.628 WC[29862:c07] classOf3 Foo<0x0002a2e4>
    2013-07-04 03:20:22.229 WC[29862:c07] classOf4 Foo<0x0002a2e4>
    2013-07-04 03:20:22.805 WC[29862:c07] classOf5 Foo<0x0002a2e4>
    2013-07-04 03:20:23.387 WC[29862:c07] classOf6 Foo<0x0002a2e4>
    2013-07-04 03:20:25.235 WC[29862:c07] classOf7 Foo<0x0002a2e4>
```

All 7 cases return the exact same value!

The most puzzling cases for me:

- classOf1 and classOf7

in the latter `self' "represents" Foo which is a class. So what's the class of a class?

- classOf5 and classOf6

Clearly "Foo" and "self" play the exact same role in this context. As they do in

- classOf3 and classOf4

It looks to me that "Foo" is a bit of magic bunny.

You can

```
@class Foo ;
```

In a way that

```
@class self ;
```

wouldn't make sense.

In the lexer to runtime generator pipeline, I can make sense of when a stream of bits changes from a bunch of character to an `identifier` to a language dependent semantic element. But I have a hard time making out the precise nature of ObjC class identifiers.

Anyone?

(This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468710/object-class-confusion) seems unrelated)

Comment: I'm guessing that in ObjC, classes aren't really objects (and thus don't have a metaclass of their own), so it's entirely possible that calling `class` on a `Class` just returns the same object deliberately.

Comment: Classes _are_ objects, @millimoose, but the second half of your sentence is the answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Right. I was confused by `Class` not being documented as such, but as a struct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see the answer in [NSObject's implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/NSObject.mm):

```
+ (Class)class {
    return self;
}

- (Class)class {
    return object_getClass(self);
}
```

Sending `class` to a class object doesn't return its metaclass, just the class object itself.

If you want the metaclass object for some reason, you have to use the runtime function [`object_getClass()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW13), like so:

```
NSLog(@"%d", class_isMetaClass(object_getClass([NSString class])));
// Prints 1
```

You can also get the metaclass for a class *name* with [`objc_getMetaClass()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-objc_getMetaClass).

Comment: I'm accepting this answer for the useful link it provides, but the question as to the nature of `Foo' as a class identifier is still not answered.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I missed that part, but I'm not quite sure what you want to know. `Foo` is just a type name. The only time you can use a literal class name to refer to the class object is when it's the reciever of a message. This is likely one of the reasons, in fact, that `+class` returns `self`: in the case where you need the class object as an argument for something but don't have an instance handy, you can say `[gardener plantLotsOf:[Oregano class]];`

Answer (score 5):

```
+ (Class) classOf1 {
    return self ;
}
```

`self` in a class method is the `Class` object of the current class, so in here `self` is the class object for class `Foo`

---

```
+ (Class) classOf2 {
    return [Foo class] ;
}
```

and here is the class object for class `Foo`

---

```
+ (Class) classOf3 {
    return [[[Foo class] new] class] ;
}
```

this is same as

```
Class fooClass = [Foo class];
id fooInstance = [fooClass new];
return [fooInstance class];
```

which again, give you the class object of class `Foo`

---

```
+ (Class) classOf4 {
    return [[self new] class] ;
}
```

same as previous one, just replace `[Foo class]` with `self`

---

```
+ (Class) classOf5 {
    return [[[self alloc] init] class] ;
}
```

same as previous one, just replace `[Foo new]` with `[[Foo alloc] init]`

---

```
+ (Class) classOf6 {
    return [[[Foo alloc] init] class] ;
}
```

same as previous one, just replace `self` with `Foo`

---

```
+ (Class) classOf7 {
    return [self class] ;
}
```

same as second one, just replace `Foo` with `self`

---

The difference between using `Foo` and `self` in a class method is that, when this method is called on a subclass, `self` will be replaced to the subclass. e.g.

```
@interface Bar : Foo
@end

Class barClass = [Bar classOf1]; // same as [Bar class]
Class fooClass = [Bar classOf2]; // same as [Foo class]
```

---

If you really want to get the class of class (i.e. metaclass), you need to use objc runtime function from [`<objc/runtime.h>`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)

```
id metaClass = objc_getMetaClass("Foo");
```