# What's happening under the hood with [ClassName class]?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

We use [ClassName class] to check against weak linked classes or classes in new version of iOS. What's happening under the hood with [ClassName class]? Does it go through NSClassFromString?

Comment: If you're trying to weak link, I believe `[ClassName class]` won't work. You have a linked reference to the class symbol, so you won't be able to use it. You'll have to use `NSClassFromString()`.

Comment: The first one compiles and links a class reference, the second one makes no assumption about the availability of classes. So no, `[ClassName class]` probably doesn't use `NSClassFromString()`

Comment: @nielsbot [It will compile and link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002304/how-to-import-social-framework-only-for-ios-6/14002350#14002350), as far as I know.

Comment: Ok, yes, if you turn on weak linking for the framework in question. I've never used that route however...

Comment: Can I use it to test a class that exists in a newer iOS SDK (say UIKit) but not in the older? That doesn't entail any weak linking.

Comment: [`+[NSObject class]` is just `return self;`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17461260/603977).

Answer (score 2):

Remember that in obj-c you can send a message to nil.

I suspect what is happening is that ClassName is nil until it is loaded by the runtime. If it is never loaded then you are basically sending the class message to nil which would return 0/nil according to the docs.

according to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW3):

> This works because if a weakly linked class is not available, sending a message to it is like sending a message to nil. If you subclass a weakly linked class and the superclass is unavailable, then the subclass also appears unavailable.

Importantly for this to work the framework must support the `NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0)` macro on its classes.

Answer (score 0):

A few things going on here. Weak linking just tells LLVM (`-weak_framework <framework_name>`) to not worry about the symbol along with optimizations. Apple recommends enabling this option when supporting previous not future run-time SDKs. You can't weak link to a framework that is not present in the SDK.

As for `[ClassName class]` it's not a `NSString` nor the toll-free bridge counterpart `CFStringRef`. It's the Objective-C class metadata

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

Identity is tested via the `NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE` macro which scans all objects that derive from the run-time metadata.

Apple Doc Ref
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW3

Comment: I'm pretty sure `[ClassName class]` returns a Class (aka `typedef struct objc_class *Class;`) not an objc_object (aka *id)

Comment: @BradAllred is correct it's actually

`@interface NSObject <NSObject> {
    Class isa;
}`